# ESXi Tools download page doesnt load

Tags: vmware-esxi

I installed `ESXi 5.5` on my server today, and I’m stuck on the point where it says:

```
Download toold to manage this host from:
http://192.168.0.2/ (STATIC)
```

I went onto my Windows client, and tried to go to the page `http://192.168.0.2/` but it doesn't load. It does however try connecting with HTTPS rather than HTTP, so something is happening.

I can ping the server and SSH to it and here is the mmap output for port 443:

```
nmap 192.168.0.2 -p443
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.2
Host is up (0.00072s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
MAC Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (Asustek Computer)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.42 seconds
```

**EDIT:** So I've managed to connect to it from my Pi using `elinks` (Of all things Lol). So I'm guessing that it is a problem with Windows 8, not the server.

**EDIT 2:** I found that I had a duplicate MAC address (the vmknic was the same as the vmnic) so, I fixed that, but still can't open the page from Windows 8. I flushed my arp tables in windows just in case. Also, I have managed to get hold of the vSphere client, but this also wont connect :(

Comment: You mention it hanging with `https` at one point. Could it be that port `443` on `192.168.0.2` is blocked? What is the output of `nmap 192.168.0.2 -p443`?

Comment: Just added in the nmap results

Comment: Check this thread here.  Seems like a similar issue: “5.5 uses OpenSSL ciphers and we're not going to be able to get it working on 2003 32-bit”  https://communities.vmware.com/thread/458401

Answer (score 1):

You mention the Windows client not being able to connect, correct?  Well [this discussion thread](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/458401) as well as this related [VMWare knowledge base article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=2049143&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&dialogID=47844467&stateId=1%200%2047848621) seems to address the issue:

> When installed on a Windows XP or Windows Server 2003 host machine,
>   the vSphere Client and vSphere PowerCLI may fail to connect to vCenter
>   Server 5.5 due to a Handshake failure. vSphere 5.5 uses the Open SSL
>   library, which, for security, is configured by default to accept only
>   connections that use strong cipher suites. On Windows XP or Windows
>   Server 2003, the vSphere Client and vSphere PowerCLI do not use strong
>   cipher suites to connect with vCenter Server. This results in the
>   error No matching cipher suite on the server side, and a Handshake
>   failure on the vSphere Client or vSphere PowerCLI side.

Two detailed options are provided:

- For **Windows Server 2003** or **64-bit Windows XP** the solution seems to be applying a hotfix from Microsoft.
- For **Windows Server 2003**, **64-bit Windows XP**, or **32-bit Windows XP** there are configuration changes recommended for the `vpxd.cfg` file located in `C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware VirtualCenter\` for the Windows-based vCenter server or in `/etc/vmware-vpx/` when using the vCenter server appliance.

Comment: No ... I'm trying to connect from my browser, to the server ... I havnt been able to download the Windows client yet ... And I'm using windows 8 not xp or server 2003